# Detecting abandoned processess in Kafka Streams 2.0

Tags: apache-kafka, event-handling, apache-kafka-streams, event-sourcing

I have this case: users collect orders as order lines. I implemented this with Kafka topic containing events with order changes, they are merged, stored in local key-value store and broadcasted as second topic with order versions.

I need to somehow react to abandoned orders - ones that were started but there was no change for at least last x hours.

Simple solution could be to scan local storage every y minutes and post event of order status change to Abandoned. It seems I cannot access store not from processor... But it is also not very elegant coding. Any suggestions are welcome.

--edit

I cannot just add puctuation to merge/validation transformer, because its output is different and should be routed elsewhere, like on this image (single kafka streams app):

[image]

so "abandoned orders processor/transformer" will be a no-op for its input (the only trigger here is time). Another thing is that i such case (as on image) my transformer gets ForwardingDisabledProcessorContext upon initialization so I cannot emit any messages in punctuator. I could just pass there kafkaTemplate bean and just produce new messages, but then whole processor/transformer is just empty shell only to access local store...

this is snippet of code I used:

```
public class AbandonedOrdersTransformer implements ValueTransformer<OrderEvent, OrderEvent> {

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext processorContext) {
        this.context = processorContext;

        stateStore = (KeyValueStore)processorContext.getStateStore(KafkaConfig.OPENED_ORDERS_STORE);

        //main scheduler
        this.context.schedule(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, (timestamp) -> {

            KeyValueIterator<String, Order> iter = this.stateStore.all();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                KeyValue<String, Order> entry = iter.next();
                if(OrderStatuses.NEW.equals(entry.value.getStatus()) &&
                    (timestamp - entry.value.getLastChanged().getTime()) > TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(4)) {

                    //SEND ABANDON EVENT "event"

                    context.forward(entry.key, event);
                }
            }
            iter.close();
            context.commit();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public OrderEvent transform(OrderEvent orderEvent) {
        //do nothing
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It seems I cannot access store not from processor..."?

Comment: I get "store not opened" error. Only if I get reference in Processor init method from context it works

Comment: That's by design. You can only access a store within a Processor -- for regular scanning of the store, you can register a punctuation: https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#id2 (you can access the store within the punctuation callback).

Comment: So this is the only way to do this? Except punctuation this processor will be totally noop (process method empty), but still will be called upon every input message. That is not very elegant coding. Also - how to emit change messages? I kstream 2.0 process() returns void (no possibility to sink output), transform() better suits, but it throws exception on context.forward() (it is for some reason forbidden and context class only throws this exception). I have to mix process with kafkatemplate producer only to get scheduled scan... Is that right?

Comment: My suggestion is to us the Processor to maintain the state, ie, use the input messages and put them into the store and do the aggregation of multiple record into one merged message until the order is complete. -- It should not be a no-op Processor. If you use the DSL, using `transform()` is better as you noticed. Maybe you can share some code snippets to show what you have tried? Also, context.forward() should work within `Transformer()` -- not sure why it throws. Can  you share the error message, too?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax check "edit" of main question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188795/discussion-between-redguy-and-matthias-j-sax).

Comment: You don't need an additional transformer for check for abandoned orders IMHO. You can register the punctuation on merge-transformer, too. To split the output, you can use `branch()` to write to different output topics (ie, the output of `merge-transformer()` should somehow indicate if it is an abandoned-order output or regular output. Last, instead of `valueTransform()` you can use `transform()` to emit data in a punctuation.